# Efficient data structures for data matching

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

What are the most efficient data structures for matching data?  For example, suppose I am presented with the follow scenario:

```
<time available> <buy or sell> <company name> <buy or sell price> <amount to buy or sell>
```

So that a file may contain:

```
0 sell yahoo $100 #1
2 sell yahoo $14  #1
2 sell yahoo $28  #1
.. 95 other yahoo sells <$125 and amount #1
3 sell yahoo $17  #1
5 sell yahoo $33  #1
9 buy yahoo  $125 #100
```

Is it possible to match this last buy with the previous 100 sells in O(n) time, where n = 100 if the buy is to be matched with the lowest selling price corresponding to the company it wants to buy from (or the one that comes first in the case of a tie)?

I know a naive solution would be to sort the list and go in order, but this takes longer than O(n) time.  What are the most efficient data structures for handling this problem and similar ones to it?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're trying to do?  That is, can you explicitly spell out what operations you want to be able to support and (relatively speaking) how frequently they occur?

Comment: If you invert your initial idea, let's say you keep an ordered list of selling prices your insertion will increase to O(log n) but you will be able to "match" at O(1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a hash map from company name to a heap of sell orders, ranked by price. Insertion of a sell order is now `O(log n)` and a buy order becomes constant if a buy doesn't use up a sell order, or `O(log n)` if it does (your problem statement doesn't specify)

Comment: The only tweak I would introduce is a hash map over pairs of heaps: a buy heap and a sell heap for each symbol.  Depending on the problem he may want to hold a buy pending until enough matching sells come along.

Comment: @phs, do you mind elaborating?  Perhaps you can construct an answer as well, if it isn't too much to ask.

Comment: Consider clarifying your question.

Answer (score 0):

As buying and selling will deal with same org , It is better to save all the buy (or) sell records in a map , like all yahoo records are be kept in a list which is hashed to a map with "yahoo" as key , this minimizes your search space . Sort with respect timestamp , price, quantity and then you can implement your desired function with a optimal cost with implementing this structure , At the time of insertion . Then for any query after this should take less time as search space was minimal .